# detect ajax request by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm working with asp controls and I have some dropdownlist which in selection go back to the server and do some action ( via asp ajax )
what I'm l looking for is detecting via jquery when the ajax call is starting 
I've tried the following call :

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
                    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                        alert("ok");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

and

```
also  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
                   alert("OK");
                });
```

but none of this worked

Comment: Show us your ajax code ?

Comment: why do you need to know that ??

Comment: in order to show a waiting image whenever ajax request is started

Answer (score 15, accepted):

well, if `$(document).ajaxStart(function() {});` is not working for you,
try a bit raw js,

```
var oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

function newXHR() {
    var realXHR = new oldXHR();
    realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(realXHR.readyState==1){
            alert('server connection established');
        }
        if(realXHR.readyState==2){
            alert('request received');
        }
        if(realXHR.readyState==3){
            alert('processing request');
        }
        if(realXHR.readyState==4){
            alert('request finished and response is ready');
        }
    }, false);
    return realXHR;
}
window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
```

it should give you all the states of a ajax request and check which one works for you, and then u can remove rest of the if conditions. you can place it outside of `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 11):

It's really **not** recommended, but you can use the [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) handlers:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    console.log('Ajax call started');
    $("#loading").show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    console.log('Ajax call completed');
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

> **Important note** Starting with jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events must be attached to `document`.

Keep in mind that if your ajax call includes `global: false`, the request will ignore the call default global configurations (which also means the the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxComplete()` callbacks will not be called.

If you don't want to set the global callbacks you can set them specifically to the ajax call you make:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET", // or POST
    url: "path",
    ....
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('Ajax call started');
        $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        console.log('Ajax call completed');
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show your `loader / waiting image` in ajax request in this way.

```
$('#loading-image').show();
$.ajax({
      url: uri,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $('.info').append(html);
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
      }
});
```

If you want to bind `global events` like  `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`.

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: no , this way won't work for because I'm not responsible of the ajax call (it's done by asp ) this is why I want to detect any ajax call

Comment: ok i will try and give you a feedback , thanks for suggestion

Comment: It does anything even it's seems correct and may work

Comment: I've tried also this   $(document).on('ajaxSend', function(){
                    $("img[id*='waiting']").show();
                    console.log("Ajax START!");
                    alert("Ajax START!");
                }); but not working

Comment: Did you try `$("#loading").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});`

Comment: Can you show me your full code or jsfiddle to check the exact problem

Comment: the entire code is too much long , what do you know excactly ??

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console, check your jquery version ?   because I don't think there is any problem what I've suggested